# Geoserver GeoTiff Raster Layer Turns Shade Pink (Not Pink Error Tiles)

Tags: raster, geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I have been given some geotiff files, sample of one is [here](http://markware.net/test.tif)

I published these files as an Image Mosaic Layer in Geoserver.

All is fine except that all the displayed geotifs, at all zoom levels are a shade of pink.

[image: Pink Shaded Tifs]

Loading the same GeoTif into QGis shows what I would expect to see in normal colors.

[image: How it should display]

1. How can I adjust this without having to process the files again.
2. If I have to ask the provider to process the files, what settings should I ask for.

Details follow

Thanks
Mark

===========================================================

My Layer Publish Page is as follows:

[image]

===========================================================

GdalInfo reports as follows:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test.tif
Size is 3231, 2201
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NAD27 / UTM zone 16N",
    GEOGCS["NAD27",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1927",
        SPHEROID["Clarke 1866",6378206.4,294.9786982139006,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7008"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6267"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4267"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-87],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","26716"]]
Origin = (690526.149508764040000,1327281.192490906900000)
Pixel Size = (8.470074670999692,-8.471304334620559)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
 AUTHOR=NGA
  CREATION_DATE=D:20070912082509-04'00'
  KEYWORDS=001
  NEATLINE=POLYGON ((690526.14950876404 1327092.3182804072,694502.74770751398 13
 27126.2206699071,703197.484547514 1327190.6997549071,710890.40089001402 1327238.
 9245984072,717780.04712851392 1327281.1924909069,717778.64260401402 1326195.7236
 159071,717810.59607576404 1321523.1942849071,717841.45503301395 1316365.28923340
 7,717871.25792651402 1311361.8114969071,717892.96077076404 1308833.6484704071,71
 4273.83173076401 1308806.8094604071,707459.30673601408 1308751.8613594072,700565
.27709876408 1308705.1485274071,694284.76414276403 1308658.5730259072,690625.882
78151397 1308635.8516504071,690526.14950876404 1327092.3182804072,690526.1495087
 6404 1327092.3182804072,690526.14950876404 1327092.3182804072))
TITLE=Map Edition
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=JPEG
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  690526.150, 1327281.192) ( 85d15' 0.18"W, 12d 0' 6.67"N)
Lower Left  (  690526.150, 1308635.852) ( 85d15' 4.07"W, 11d49'59.90"N)
Upper Right (  717892.961, 1327281.192) ( 84d59'55.65"W, 12d 0' 0.61"N)
Lower Right (  717892.961, 1308635.852) ( 85d 0' 0.10"W, 11d49'53.92"N)
Center      (  704209.555, 1317958.522) ( 85d 7'29.99"W, 11d55' 0.38"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Overviews: 1616x1101, 808x551, 404x276, 202x138
Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Overviews of mask band: 1616x1101, 808x551, 404x276, 202x138
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Overviews: 1616x1101, 808x551, 404x276, 202x138
Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Overviews of mask band: 1616x1101, 808x551, 404x276, 202x138
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
Overviews: 1616x1101, 808x551, 404x276, 202x138
Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Overviews of mask band: 1616x1101, 808x551, 404x276, 202x138
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
Overviews: 1616x1101, 808x551, 404x276, 202x138
```

Comment: have you checked the order of your bands ? Sometimes, the recomputation of the statistics can help. (gdal_translate with -stats option)

Comment: Thanks, but we will have several hundred of these, I was looking for a solution on the Geoserver side, but if we have to reprocess them, so be it, but would like to see if there is a server side way to resolve this before starting down that path.

Answer (score 0):

If you already opened your file into QGIS then right click the layer name and choose `Save As...`:

[image]

Then try to produce a `Rendered image` and a `VRT`, like below:

[image]

You'll obtain two files: a `tif` and a `vrt`. Import these two files in your GeoServer, like you did before. Now everything must be ok, at least in my tests!

Comment: Thanks, but we will have several hundred of these, I was looking for a solution on the Geoserver side, but if we have to reprocess them, so be it.

Comment: If have the original image (with hundreds of GB, perhaps) you can render that image instead, and you only need to preserve the VRT Tiles resolution (3231 x 2201).

Comment: Or you can build, in an instant, with QGIS, a Raster catalog for all your tiles, and upload all your tiles in GeoServer together with the raster catalog (**Raster > Miscellaneous > Build Virtual Raster (Catalog)**)